# Libm relocation error when building Qt 5 for Nitrogen6x

Tags: qt, build, arm, debian, libc

I am trying to build Qt 5 on a *Nitrogen6x board* powered by an *i.MX6Q`.

I've installed *Debian/wheezy* on the board and am using an *Ubuntu 12.10* machine for cross-compiling.

Configuring Qt works like a charm but I am stuck in the make step.
This is the configure script I run:

```
./configure -v -opensource -confirm-license  -reduce-relocations -no-pch -no-xcb -no-opengl -opengl es2  -qt-libpng -qt-zlib -qt-xkbcommon -qt-xcb -qt-pcre -qt-libjpeg -qt-sql-mysql -optimized-qmake\
   -make libs -device imx6 \
   -compile-examples   \
   -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/finn/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- \
   -sysroot /media/finn/d72e3b65-b529-4e5c-9d30-872e1b0c9973 \
   -prefix /opt/qt5
```

And this is the error I receive about 5 minutes into the make process:

```
/home/finn/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: 
/media/finn/d72e3b65-b529-4e5c-9d30-872e1b0c9973/usr/lib/libm.a(mpa.o): relocation R_ARM_THM_MOVW_ABS_NC against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/media/finn/d72e3b65-b529-4e5c-9d30-872e1b0c9973/usr/lib/libm.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've run into the same error before, when it was trying to access libz.a but adding the qt-zlib parameter to the configure command fixed that issue.

Many articles state that affected applications/libraries should be recompiled, however I don't think that's possible as libm is part of libc6.

I already tried reinstalling it using `aptitude remove libc6-dev zlib1g-dev g++-4.6`
and `apt-get install gcc g++ make flex bison openssl libssl-dev perl perl-base perl-modules libperl-dev build-essential`

Sadly this did not fix the problem.

Debian has been installed using the official network installer as well as a Kernel and an Overlay provided by Boundarydevices, the manufacturer of the board.

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?

My next step would be to install a completely new Debian system but I would really like to avoid that.

### Edit

Compiling qtbase with -static option works for me, however I am running into this error when trying to build qtdeclarative during the make step:

```
    /home/finn/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/home/finn/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/home/finn/qt/qtbase/lib/libQt5Core.a(qlibrary_unix.o): In function `QLibraryPrivate::load_sys()':
qlibrary_unix.cpp:(.text+0xaac): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/home/finn/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lqxcb
/home/finn/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
/home/finn/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### Edit 2 - Solution

I fixed the problem and successfully compiled Qt.
All I needed to do was reinstall Ubuntu. It sure isn't an elegant solution but it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> libm.a(mpa.o): relocation R_ARM_THM_MOVW_ABS_NC against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object

Translation: you are trying to link non-`-fPIC` compiled object file (`mpa.o` from `libm.a`) into a shared library. You can't do that.

You need to either find/install `libm.so` for your target, or configure qt5 to not build shared library (possibly with `--disable-shared` option).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Compiling qt with -static option did the trick.

Qtbase has successfully been build and qtjsbackend works like a charm too, however I am having troubles building qtdeclarative.

The compiler claims that it can not find crti.o, libpthread.so.0 and other files which are present on the target.

I've posted the error message in my original question.
Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

A litte late, but I found the problem/solution:

The problem is the *sysroot*. Normally gcc links to shared libraries. But when it cant find it, gcc uses the static libraries (.a). When you look in `[sysroot]/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` the shared libraries are not in this place. There are only symlinks to `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`. So gcc looks for the shared libraries on you host-pc, where it can not find them.

## Solution

Create just the right symlink. (Here's an example for libglib, the `X` is the version number)

```
ln -s [sysroot]/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib.so.X \
      [sysroot]/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib.so
```

(Dont forget to remove the old symlink and create it after compiling successfully; i just do the following before compiling:

```
mv file.so file.so.backup
```

## another solution

Another solution is to change the absolut symlinks to relative ones.
For Example, if your library is `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib.so.X` and you need a link in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/`, you just do:

```
ln -s ../../../lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib.so.X \
      [sysroot]/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib.so
```