# Qt cross compilation from x86 Ubuntu to ARM Beagle Bone almost finished with strange mistake R_ARM_THM_MOVW_ABS_NC

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, arm, beagleboneblack

I already spent lots of time on trying to crosscompile Qt 5.2.1 (as a recommended and stable one) from my x86 Ubuntu to ARM Beagle Bone Black. After about 20 minutes the compilation ends with a strange mistake. This is the end of the compilation console output:

```
rm -f libQt5Core.so.5.2.1 libQt5Core.so libQt5Core.so.5 libQt5Core.so.5.2
/home/piotrek/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --sysroot=/media/rootfs -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-O1 -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,--dynamic-list,/home/piotrek/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtbase/src/corelib/QtCore.dynlist -Wl,-soname,libQt5Core.so.5 -o libQt5Core.so.5.2.1 .obj/qabstractanimation.o .obj/qvariantanimation.o .obj/qpropertyanimation.o .obj/qanimationgroup.o .obj/qsequentialanimationgroup.o .obj/qparallelanimationgroup.o .obj/qpauseanimation.o .obj/qatomic_unix.o .obj/qglobal.o .obj/qglobalstatic.o .obj/qlibraryinfo.o .obj/qmalloc.o .obj/qnumeric.o .obj/qlogging.o .obj/qatomic.o .obj/qexception.o .obj/qresultstore.o .obj/qfutureinterface.o .obj/qfuturewatcher.o .obj/qmutex.o .obj/qreadwritelock.o .obj/qrunnable.o .obj/qmutexpool.o .obj/qsemaphore.o .obj/qthread.o .obj/qthreadpool.o .obj/qthreadstorage.o .obj/qthread_unix.o .obj/qwaitcondition_unix.o .obj/qarraydata.o .obj/qbitarray.o .obj/qbytearray.o .obj/qbytearraymatcher.o .obj/qcollator.o .obj/qcommandlineoption.o .obj/qcommandlineparser.o .obj/qcryptographichash.o .obj/qdatetime.o .obj/qdatetimeparser.o .obj/qeasingcurve.o .obj/qelapsedtimer.o .obj/qfreelist.o .obj/qhash.o .obj/qline.o .obj/qlinkedlist.o .obj/qlist.o .obj/qlocale.o .obj/qlocale_tools.o .obj/qpoint.o .obj/qmap.o .obj/qmargins.o .obj/qmessageauthenticationcode.o .obj/qcontiguouscache.o .obj/qrect.o .obj/qregexp.o .obj/qregularexpression.o .obj/qrefcount.o .obj/qshareddata.o .obj/qsharedpointer.o .obj/qsimd.o .obj/qsize.o .obj/qstring.o .obj/qstringbuilder.o .obj/qstringlist.o .obj/qtextboundaryfinder.o .obj/qtimeline.o .obj/qtimezone.o .obj/qtimezoneprivate.o .obj/qunicodetools.o .obj/qvector.o .obj/qvsnprintf.o .obj/qelapsedtimer_unix.o .obj/qlocale_unix.o .obj/qtimezoneprivate_tz.o .obj/adler32.o .obj/compress.o .obj/crc32.o .obj/deflate.o .obj/gzclose.o .obj/gzlib.o .obj/gzread.o .obj/gzwrite.o .obj/infback.o .obj/inffast.o .obj/inflate.o .obj/inftrees.o .obj/trees.o .obj/uncompr.o .obj/zutil.o .obj/qlocale_icu.o .obj/qcollator_icu.o .obj/qtimezoneprivate_icu.o .obj/pcre16_byte_order.o .obj/pcre16_chartables.o .obj/pcre16_compile.o .obj/pcre16_config.o .obj/pcre16_dfa_exec.o .obj/pcre16_exec.o .obj/pcre16_fullinfo.o .obj/pcre16_get.o .obj/pcre16_globals.o .obj/pcre16_jit_compile.o .obj/pcre16_maketables.o .obj/pcre16_newline.o .obj/pcre16_ord2utf16.o .obj/pcre16_refcount.o .obj/pcre16_string_utils.o .obj/pcre16_study.o .obj/pcre16_tables.o .obj/pcre16_ucd.o .obj/pcre16_utf16_utils.o .obj/pcre16_valid_utf16.o .obj/pcre16_version.o .obj/pcre16_xclass.o .obj/harfbuzz-buffer.o .obj/harfbuzz-gdef.o .obj/harfbuzz-gsub.o .obj/harfbuzz-gpos.o .obj/harfbuzz-impl.o .obj/harfbuzz-open.o .obj/harfbuzz-stream.o .obj/harfbuzz-shaper-all.o .obj/qharfbuzz.o .obj/qabstractfileengine.o .obj/qbuffer.o .obj/qdatastream.o .obj/qdataurl.o .obj/qtldurl.o .obj/qdebug.o .obj/qdir.o .obj/qdiriterator.o .obj/qfile.o .obj/qfiledevice.o .obj/qfileinfo.o .obj/qipaddress.o .obj/qiodevice.o .obj/qlockfile.o .obj/qnoncontiguousbytedevice.o .obj/qprocess.o .obj/qtextstream.o .obj/qtemporarydir.o .obj/qtemporaryfile.o .obj/qresource.o .obj/qresource_iterator.o .obj/qsavefile.o .obj/qstandardpaths.o .obj/qurl.o .obj/qurlidna.o .obj/qurlquery.o .obj/qurlrecode.o .obj/qsettings.o .obj/qfsfileengine.o .obj/qfsfileengine_iterator.o .obj/qfilesystemwatcher.o .obj/qfilesystemwatcher_polling.o .obj/qfilesystementry.o .obj/qfilesystemengine.o .obj/qfileselector.o .obj/qloggingcategory.o .obj/qloggingregistry.o .obj/qfsfileengine_unix.o .obj/qfilesystemengine_unix.o .obj/qlockfile_unix.o .obj/qprocess_unix.o .obj/qfilesystemiterator_unix.o .obj/qstandardpaths_unix.o .obj/qfilesystemwatcher_inotify.o .obj/qabstractitemmodel.o .obj/qabstractproxymodel.o .obj/qitemselectionmodel.o .obj/qidentityproxymodel.o .obj/qsortfilterproxymodel.o .obj/qstringlistmodel.o .obj/qjson.o .obj/qjsondocument.o .obj/qjsonobject.o .obj/qjsonarray.o .obj/qjsonvalue.o .obj/qjsonwriter.o .obj/qjsonparser.o .obj/qpluginloader.o .obj/qfactoryloader.o .obj/quuid.o .obj/qlibrary.o .obj/qelfparser_p.o .obj/qmachparser.o .obj/qlibrary_unix.o .obj/qabstracteventdispatcher.o .obj/qabstractnativeeventfilter.o .obj/qbasictimer.o .obj/qeventloop.o .obj/qcoreapplication.o .obj/qcoreevent.o .obj/qmetaobject.o .obj/qmetatype.o .obj/qmetaobjectbuilder.o .obj/qmimedata.o .obj/qobject.o .obj/qobjectcleanuphandler.o .obj/qsignalmapper.o .obj/qsocketnotifier.o .obj/qtimer.o .obj/qtranslator.o .obj/qvariant.o .obj/qcoreglobaldata.o .obj/qsharedmemory.o .obj/qsystemsemaphore.o .obj/qpointer.o .obj/qmath.o .obj/qsystemerror.o .obj/qcore_unix.o .obj/qcrashhandler.o .obj/qeventdispatcher_unix.o .obj/qtimerinfo_unix.o .obj/qeventdispatcher_glib.o .obj/qsharedmemory_unix.o .obj/qsystemsemaphore_unix.o .obj/qisciicodec.o .obj/qlatincodec.o .obj/qtextcodec.o .obj/qtsciicodec.o .obj/qutfcodec.o .obj/qicucodec.o .obj/qstatemachine.o .obj/qabstractstate.o .obj/qstate.o .obj/qfinalstate.o .obj/qhistorystate.o .obj/qabstracttransition.o .obj/qsignaltransition.o .obj/qeventtransition.o .obj/qmimedatabase.o .obj/qmimetype.o .obj/qmimemagicrulematcher.o .obj/qmimetypeparser.o .obj/qmimemagicrule.o .obj/qmimeglobpattern.o .obj/qmimeprovider.o .obj/qxmlstream.o .obj/qxmlutils.o .obj/qrc_mimetypes.o .obj/moc_qabstractanimation_p.o .obj/moc_qnamespace.o .obj/moc_qthread.o .obj/moc_qthreadpool.o .obj/moc_qfuturewatcher.o .obj/moc_qeasingcurve.o .obj/moc_qlocale.o .obj/moc_qtimeline.o .obj/moc_qfile.o .obj/moc_qfiledevice.o .obj/moc_qiodevice.o .obj/moc_qnoncontiguousbytedevice_p.o .obj/moc_qtextstream_p.o .obj/moc_qtemporaryfile.o .obj/moc_qsavefile.o .obj/moc_qsettings.o .obj/moc_qfilesystemwatcher_p.o .obj/moc_qfilesystemwatcher_polling_p.o .obj/moc_qfilesystemwatcher_inotify_p.o .obj/moc_qabstractitemmodel.o .obj/moc_qstringlistmodel.o .obj/moc_qpluginloader.o .obj/moc_qlibrary.o .obj/moc_qfactoryloader_p.o .obj/moc_qabstracteventdispatcher.o .obj/moc_qeventloop.o .obj/moc_qcoreapplication.o .obj/moc_qcoreevent.o .obj/moc_qmimedata.o .obj/moc_qsocketnotifier.o .obj/moc_qtimer.o .obj/moc_qtranslator.o .obj/moc_qobjectcleanuphandler.o .obj/moc_qsharedmemory.o .obj/moc_qeventdispatcher_unix_p.o .obj/moc_qeventdispatcher_glib_p.o .obj/moc_qabstractstate.o .obj/moc_qstate.o .obj/moc_qfinalstate.o .obj/moc_qhistorystate.o .obj/moc_qabstracttransition.o .obj/moc_qsignaltransition.o .obj/moc_qeventtransition.o  -lrt -ldl -lpthread -licui18n -licuuc -lm -ldl -pthread -L/media/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lrt 
/home/piotrek/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /media/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gmain.o): relocation R_ARM_THM_MOVW_ABS_NC against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/media/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5.2.1] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/piotrek/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtbase/src/corelib'
make[2]: *** [sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/piotrek/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtbase/src'
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/piotrek/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtbase'
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

I start the compilation process with standard command:

```
sudo make -j4
```

I believe the important part of the error output is:

```
(libglib_2_0_la-gmain.o): relocation R_ARM_THM_MOVW_ABS_NC against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

My Qt was configured with following command: 
(device linux-beagleboard-g++ was edited for the Beaglebone)

```
sudo ./configure -prefix /home/piotrek/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0 -device linux-beagleboard-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/piotrek/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /media/rootfs -release -opensource -confirm-license -opengl es2 -v -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -qt-harfbuzz -qt-pcre -qt-xcb -qt-xkbcommon
```

How can i eliminate this error and push the compilation foreward? Where does it come form?

Comment: Have you tried the solution from https://forum.qt.io/topic/40115/linking-issues-with-qt-5-2-1-when-building-for-arm/3 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894541/libm-relocation-error-when-building-qt-5-for-nitrogen6x ? Have you tried to search for a solution first? If yes - what was the problem?

Comment: I haven't found the solution, fixing the symlinks as described in https://forum.qt.io/topic/40115/linking-issues-with-qt-5-2-1-when-building-for-arm/3 worked for me.

Comment: So you didn't find a solution but that worked for you? I'm confused?

Comment: That was over a year ago, but I think the part 'I haven't found the solution' referred to the question from previous post 'Have you tried to search for a solution first?' as 'Yes, I googled it well before asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to your problem, I am asking anyways. Why do you to use Qt5.2.1. It quite old and lacking many improvements of newer versions.

Comment: I started with Qt5.4, but got stuck with this error: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40458 . They recommended changing Qt version to an older one so i chose version 5.2.1 as described in many beaglebone tutorials