# LLVM crosscompile can't create dynamic relocation R_ARM_ABS32

Tags: llvm, cross-compiling, libstdc++

I am trying to cross-compile for the Raspberry Pi with LLVM using LLD as the linker with the gnu stdlib implementation. I get a load of the following warnings, which refer to relocations inside read-only sections, all contained within the standard library implementation (seems to happen for c and cpp).

```
ld.lld: error: can't create dynamic relocation R_ARM_ABS32 against local symbol in readonly segment; recompile object files with -fPIC or pass '-Wl,-z,notext' to allow text relocations in the output
    >>> defined in /home/ted/cross.llvm.raspbian/sysroot/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6.3.0/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.a(s_atan.o)
    >>> referenced by s_atan.o:(atanMp.constprop.0) in archive /home/ted/cross.llvm.raspbian/sysroot/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6.3.0/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.a
```

While the diagnostic tells me to use `-z,notext` this is [apparently bad](http://llvm.1065342.n5.nabble.com/llvm-dev-LLD-Can-t-create-dynamic-relocation-R-X86-64-64-against-local-symbol-in-readonly-segment-tp107341p107383.html). Is there another way to fix the issue, or am I using incorrect flags for the cross-compilation?

Side note: for the cross-compilation I use

```
clang++ --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --sysroot=./sysroot -fuse-ld=lld --verbose test.cpp -o test
```

`./sysroot` contains `/usr` and `/lib` from the Raspberry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by default clang compiler tries to link dynamic libraries. And your dynamic library is (most probably) a *symlink to absolute path*.

To me it is like that:

```bash
$ ls -l /Volumes/AlphaRacing/emlid-rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm*
# ...
/Volumes/AlphaRacing/emlid-rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so -> /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6
```

As long as you cross-compile, you the real path of symlink source is different.

So you have two options:

1. Compile with `-static` flag.
2. Fix those symlinks to use relative paths. But beware, there are plenty of them.

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894541/libm-relocation-error-when-building-qt-5-for-nitrogen6x), it helped me to figure out this problem.